# controller action contains more than one model method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rubymine

I have a simple `update` action in a `Rails 4` controller:

```
#more stuff here
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.username} updated"
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

However, RubyMine is warning about `@user.update` and `@user.username`:

> This inspection warns if a controller action contains more than one model method call, after the initial .find or .new. It’s recommended that you implement all business logic inside the model class, and use a single method to access it.

I don't see `more than one model method call` here. Can some one explain what is going on?

**EDIT** - I have something similar in the `create` action without warns, so I believe there is something to do with `user_params`...

```
def create
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.username} created"
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `username` is a method in model where you merge user `first_name` and `last_name`.

I guess `@user.update(user_params)` and `@user.username` are your both method calls. One that saves the model, another that sets the user full name in flash notice.

It's just a warning from rubymine that just recommends you some actions to do, not necessary to follow them.

Comment: `username` is just an attribute for the `User`, and I don't get the same warning for the create action...

Comment: `username` is still a method call to model User, but can't say why it won't give you the same warning for create action too.